# What Nvidia driver should I use - I have a Nvidia GeForce 1050TI

Tags: drivers, nvidia

The first time I used Nvidia's site and entered my graphics card info & OS, it told me to use version 375.XXX  which I think was last updated in 2018.  I then got to a very similar page on Nvidia that asked the same questions and it listed a number of drivers with 460.xx being the highest release number and it also said 450 - both of which were released on 01/07/2021 and they are both available for 64bit Linux.

So I have no idea which driver I should use.  I'm always nervous about installing these drivers b/c 2x I've installed new graphics drivers ad it completely corrupted my OS  (this was 3-5 years ago with a GeForce 640).
|Graphics card|
|-----------------|
|Gigabyte GTX 1050 Ti Windforce OC 4GB GDDR5 128-bit PCI-E Graphic Card (GV-N105TWF2OC-4GD) |

Comment: Use the driver suggested by the system. They all should work.

Comment: On my 18.04 system with a GeForce GTX 1050Ti I am currently using the 450 driver from the Ubuntu restricted repository.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ubuntu-drivers devices` to find what the system recommends to you, if there is no output, then your present driver is already recommended.